# Do I correctly understand empirical c.d.f?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

The below definition comes from Wikipedia page:

> [image]

Could you please verify if I understand the concept correctly? Thank you so much!

> For each $(t,n)$, the empirical c.d.f $F_n(t): \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is a random variable defined by $$F_n(t) (\omega) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,t]} (X_i(\omega))$$

Comment: Yes, you wrote exactly the same as in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other users confirmed that my understanding is correct. I posted it here to close my question.

> For each $(t,n)$, the empirical c.d.f $F_n(t): \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is a random variable defined by $$F_n(t) (\omega) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,t]} (X_i(\omega))$$